# How do I install pipx on windows?

Tags: python, testing, automation, pip

I'm currently trying to follow the guides from CumulusCi and I'm having some trouble installing pipx inside my computer.

I already have installed Python 3 and I'm currently running the following command:

```
pip install --user pipx

'''

The result is the following:
```

Requirement already satisfied:

```
pipx in c:\users\aharo\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (0.16.1.0)
```

I set up the path environmental variables, and when I'm running pipx list is telling me the following:

```
pipx : The term 'pipx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pipx list
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pipx:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 6):

I use windows 10

I went to cmd wrote the below

`python -m pip install --user pipx`
`python -m pipx ensurepath`
`python -m pipx install eth-brownie`

went back to visual studio code and wrote: `python -m pipx ensurepath`

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem, but quick fix is to run it as `py -m pipx list`.
I guess, it was installed to some another folder, due to windows...